# Where can I find a list of all the reference implementations for Java EE 6?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6

Do you know if there is a list with all the reference implementation for every component of Java EE 6? I.e. GlassFish is the reference container, Hibernate Validator for validation, etc.

Comment: Why is this closed? This question is not soliciting debate, arguments, polling or extended discussion. I see that it already has an accepted answer (which is pretty good, BTW), but this is not a reason for closure.

Comment: Requesting an off-site resource is one of the proscribe classes of question.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Here's an overview of all RI's (and alternatives).

#### Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 (Java EE 6) - [JSR 316](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316)

- [Oracle Glassfish 3.x](http://glassfish.java.net) (RI)
- [JBoss AS 6.x and 7.x](http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/)
- [IBM WebSphere 8.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/)

#### Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) 2.2 - [JSR 222](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222)

- [Oracle JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/) (RI, used in Glassfish 3)
- [Oracle Metro](http://metro.java.net/)

#### Java API for XML-Based Web Services (JAX-WS) 2.2 - [JSR 224](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224)

- [Oracle JAX-WS](http://jax-ws.java.net/) (RI, used in Glassfish 3)
- [Oracle Metro](http://metro.java.net/)
- [Apache CXF 2.x](http://cxf.apache.org/)

#### Contexts and Dependency Injection for Java - [JSR 299](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299) and [JSR 330](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/summary?id=330)

- [JBoss Weld](http://seamframework.org/Weld) (RI, used in Glassfish 3)
- [Apache OpenWebBeans](http://openwebbeans.apache.org)
- [Resin CanDI](http://code.google.com/p/candi-stripes/downloads/list) (JSR299 only)

#### Bean Validation 1.0 [JSR 303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303)

- [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) (RI, used in Glassfish 3)
- [Agimatec Validation](http://code.google.com/p/agimatec-validation/)
- [GWT Validation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-validation/)

#### Java API for RESTful Web Services (JAX-RS) 1.1 - [JSR 311](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311)

- [Oracle Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) (RI, used in Glassfish 3)
- [JBoss RESTEasy](http://jboss.org/resteasy) (used in JBoss AS)
- [Apache CXF 2.x](http://cxf.apache.org/)
- [Apache Wink](http://incubator.apache.org/wink/)
- [Grails JAX-RS](http://code.google.com/p/grails-jaxrs/)

#### JavaServer Faces 2.0 - [JSR 314](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314)

- [Oracle Mojarra](http://javaserverfaces.java.net) (RI, used in Glassfish 3)
- [Apache MyFaces 2.0](http://myfaces.apache.org/core20/)

#### Java Servlet 3.0 and JavaServer Pages 2.2/Expression Language 2.2 - [JSR 315](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) and [JSR 245](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=245)

- [Oracle Glassfish 3.x](http://glassfish.java.net) (RI)
- [Resin 4.0.1+](http://www.caucho.com/resin-4.0/changes/resin-4.0.1.xtp)
- [Apache Geronimo 3.0](http://geronimo.apache.org/)
- [Apache Tomcat 7.0](http://tomcat.apache.org/)
- [Eclipse Jetty 8.0](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/)

#### Java Persistence API (JPA) 2.0 - [JSR 317](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=317)

- [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) (RI, used in Glassfish 3)
- [OpenJPA 2.0](http://openjpa.apache.org/)
- [Hibernate 3.5.x](http://www.hibernate.org/)

#### Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB3) 3.1 - [JSR 318](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=318)

- [Oracle Glassfish 3.x](http://glassfish.java.net) (RI)
- [Apache TomEE and OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/) (EJB 3.1 lite)
- [BuzyBeans](http://code.google.com/p/buzybeans/) (EJB 3.1 lite)

Comment: OpenEJB only implements upto EJB3.0 not yet 3.1

Comment: Never noticed this question... and answer. Good work. And +1

Comment: @Pas: you've ever edited it :)

Comment: LOL! Indeed. On the basis of my vote not being there, I was 100% sure this was another question/answer. Why I didn't vote it at that time is beyond me. Drunk maybe? ;)

Comment: @Pascal: Hi BalusC and Pascal: I heard that Apache OpenWebBean implementation of CDI is much mature and faster than WELD. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: @Harry: I haven't used CDI closely in any way.

Comment: can someone clarify / split what is the difference between 299 and 330 and what is (Google) Guice as a JSR-330 implementation? That's confusing. Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14708725 JSR-299 is the EE enhancement of JSR-330, right?!

Comment: @childno.de: 299 is the API (the specification/blueprint) and 330 is the standard impl (the concrete code).

Comment: @BalusC thanks. seems to I got it: 330 just provides the interface "definition" (standard impl.) from java but how it is handled and what really happens in the application container is made e.g. in Weld (as Reference Implementation). right?

Comment: Thanks @BalusC, These days, I surfing on the Stackoverflow, Your answers releay help me out.

Comment: Do you plan on updating the answer? For example, JSR 339: Jax-RS 2.0 was released 4 years ago. Soon JAX-RS 2.1 with SSE :)

Comment: @Mark Question explicitly asked about Java EE 6.

Comment: My mistake. I wonder if it won't be valuble to have answers for 7 and soon 8.