# What is Weld, JSR-299?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, cdi, jboss-weld

I've found lots of tutorials showing Weld code samples, but not an introductory overview.

Could you please suggest an introductory article, or answer the following:

- What does Weld do/give you?
- How does it relate to Java EE 6?
- How would one use it in a Java EE 6 project?
- If one uses it in a Java EE 6 project, what is it supplanting, if anything?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

> *What does Weld do/give you?*

[Weld](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/) is the reference implementation of the abstract [JSR-299 API](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=299), which is better known as CDI, Contexts and Dependency Injection, an API which is provided through [`javax.enterprise.context`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/package-summary.html) and [`javax.enterprise.inject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/inject/package-summary.html) packages.

> *How does it relate to Java EE 6?*

JSR-299 is part of [Java EE 6 (JSR-316)](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316).

> *How would one use it in a Java EE 6 project?*

Weld or another JSR-299 implementation is already supplied by the Java EE 6 container (the application server). If yours doesn't ship with Weld, but with another JSR-299 implementation, and you want to use Weld instead, then you need to consult the documentation of the container in question how to replace it.

> *If one uses it in a Java EE 6 project, what is it supplanting, if anything?*

Spring (as it was during the dark J2EE ages).

#### See also:

- [List of all (reference) implementations of JEE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296678/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-all-the-reference-implementations-for-jee6/2300328#2300328)
- [Introduction to Weld](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/)