# Where can I find JavaEE packages' sources?

Tags: jakarta-ee, documentation, weblogic

I'm developing a JavaEE system (distributed on Weblogic App Server), but I don't have the sources for the JavaEE packages (javax.ejb.*, for instance).

Where can I find the sources (not javadoc) for these packages?

Comment: Most of the source code will not be of any value, as most 'classes' are interfaces only. Nevertheless, I'm interested as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Java EE is an abstract API. It exist of just contracts (as you see in javadocs), not concrete code. The application servers are the concrete implementations. So, if you're looking for the source, you should look at the application server vendor's homepage for a source code download link. However, you're unlucky with Weblogic. It is not open source. I've never used Weblogic (I am an open source fan), so I'm not sure if the source is provided along the Weblogic license, you might want to contact Weblogic support team.

Other servers, like [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/), [Payara](https://payara.fish), [WildFly](https://wildfly.org), etc are open source. [WebSphere](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/websphere-application-server) has also a ["Community Edition"](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/websphere-liberty/) which is open source. You could grab the `javax.*` API source code from any of them, but there is no guarantee that they are exactly the same as Weblogic uses. And still then, they do not provide the concrete Weblogic implementation code (like as the code in `org.apache.*`, `com.sun.*` and `org.wildfly.*` packages in aforementioned open source servers).

#### See also:

- [What exactly is Java EE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096)

Comment: BTW, I'm really curious where the JEE API source really comes from - where can it be found except repo1.maven.org. I could not find it on the Oracle page, and packages available in Maven bear Sun's copyright.

Comment: @MaDa: from Glassfish, the Reference Implementation. Related: [Where can i find a list of all the reference implementations for JEE6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296678) Please note that the Java EE download from oracle.com basically contains Glassfish along optionally Netbeans and a bunch of docs. Related: [What exactly is Java EE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295096)

Answer (score 4):

Try in the default [Maven repository](http://search.maven.org); search for "javax.ejb", then download the source. That's quite often the easiest way, saving you from clicking through EULAs and the like.

That said, this source code is only good for plugging into an IDE to get source code completion — implementations are application-server specific (see Balusc answer).